# How to get JSON array response data in angular2 application

Tags: arrays, json, angular, angular2-directives

I have JSON response like below. What I want to do is get below JSON response into my angular2 application. but I couldn't get the expected output. Kindly give opinions about my coding solution.

```
{
"staffinfo": {
    "id": 3,
    "DeptID": 2,
    "OfficeID": 3,
    "FirstName": "Loreiya",
    "LastName": "Cheng",
    "DOB": "1991-04-02",
    "IsWorking": 1,
    "created_at": "2017-10-22 13:07:15",
    "updated_at": "2017-10-22 13:07:15"
},
"officeinfo": {
    "id": 3,
    "Name": "Finance-Payroll ",
    "Address": "No 20/1, Cross street, dalas, Block A ",
    "Description": "staff salary division ",
    "created_at": "2017-10-24 00:00:00",
    "updated_at": "2017-10-24 00:00:00"
}
```

}

this data should display in my **department.component.html** file

```
 <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="depid">Department</label>
    <select name="depid" id="depid" class="form-control" ngModel>
      <option value="1">HR</option>
      <option value="2">Finance</option>
      <option value="3">Marketing</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
</form>

<div *ngFor="let dep of department">
  {{ dep.staffinfo }}
</div>
```

this is my **department.component.ts** file (I could get Members found alert without any errors)

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from "@angular/forms";
import { StaffService } from "../staff.service";
import { Department } from "../department.interface";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-department',
  templateUrl: './department.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./department.component.css']
})
export class DepartmentComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() department: Department[];

  constructor(private staffService: StaffService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    this.staffService.getDept(form.value.depid)
    .subscribe(
      () => alert('Members found')
    );
    form.reset();
  }
}
```

this is my **staff.service.ts** file to call back-end service

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Response, Headers } from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class StaffService{
  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

getDept(depid: number): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/dept/' + depid)
    .map(
      (response: Response) => {
        return response.json().department;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

console ouput

[image]

Postman JSON response 
[image]

this is my backend controller (Laravel 5.4) to call front-end Angular2 application.

```
    public function getDeptinfo($id)
   {
     $staffinfo = Staff::find($id);

     if($staffinfo){
         $officeinfo = Office::find($staffinfo['OfficeID']);
     }

     $response = [
         'staffinfo' => $staffinfo,
         'officeinfo' => $officeinfo
     ];

     return response()->json($response, 200);
   }
```

Comment: Will you please post full response ?

Comment: sorry I didn't catch you. I've already post all the code samples

Comment: Will you please post the out put of console.log(response.json().department);

Comment: PLease post json response

Comment: Its not array as you can see from Postman JSON response

Comment: you say, **can't get the expected output**, what does that mean? What do you expect the output to be precisely?

Comment: hello AJT, I want to get JSON response to my html

Comment: Well that was my point exactly, that what _is_ your expected output in the html? What do you want to show? But yeah, I see you accepted an answer, but always should be clear on what you are trying to do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign reposnse to the `department` :

**Service :**

```
getDept(depid: number): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/dept/' + depid)
    .map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }
}
```

Replace your `DepartmentComponent` with this :

```
export class DepartmentComponent implements OnInit {
    department: Department;

    constructor(private staffService: StaffService) { }

    onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
        this.staffService.getDept(form.value.depid).subscribe((res) => {
            this.department = res;
        });
        form.reset();
    }
}
```

**Template side**

Replace this :

```
<div *ngFor="let dep of department">
  {{ dep.staffinfo }}
</div>
```

With :

```
{{ department?.staffinfo | json }}
```

Comment: Hello Vivek, unfortunately, this didn't work for me. ----- TypeError: Cannot read property 'staffinfo' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (DepartmentComponent.html:15)

Comment: @aselanuwan, please check now;

Comment: @aselanuwan, please check now;

Comment: what do you mean? I already have chosen your answer as a correct one. I didn't devote to you.

Comment: yes you have but if you also upvote the answer , that would be good